# How do I create a different array from an existing array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api

Hi I am trying create a  new array from an exisiting array in React, but I need to cut down on the information in the  array.

Currently the raw json data looks like this:

```
[{"id":"1",
"first":"'Norm'",
"last":"'Macdonald'",
"student_id":"78",
"email":"Hello@gmail.com",
"phone":"3603603600",
"address":"782 st",
"postbaccalaureate":"No",
"withdrawing":"No",
"veterans_benefits":"No",
"active":"Yes",
"non_stem_majors":"None"}
```

I use Axios to create an array in React. Then I need to create another array that will look like this:

```
[
{
label: first + last + student_id, 
value: id
}
]
```

for every element in the above array. I am currently using map, but it is not working. Here is my current idea that is not working:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const temp = students.map((student) => {
      {label: student.first + ", " + student.last + " " + student.student_id, value: student.id}
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a return, so `return  {label: studen ....`

Comment: "_but it is not working_"  doesn't give us much info on what isn't actually working. Is the value in `temp` wrong, are you getting an error, etc.